# How can I stop the system changing name extensions of my files?

Tags: terminal, script, perl

I have a created an executable Perl script, starting with

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
```

and have called it `t`. So when I launch `./t` on the Terminal the script is executed and everything is fine.

But apparently some hidden daemon in my computer does not like this, and after a few minutes of existence under the name `t`, the file's name is automatically changed into `t.pl`.

I find this unacceptable. Don't I have the right to name files as I want on my machine? It is not a system file, just a personal script in my `home` directory. How can I avoid this intrusion of Apple into the private life of my files?

Comment: What editor are you using to create the file?

Comment: That‘s not standard behavior in macOS. What other applications, utilities etc do you have running? With which editor do you create the file? If you run `cp t t1`, does the copy get changed as well?

Comment: I use BBEdit to create the file. I just did the test: after a `mv t.pl t` it takes about three seconds to be transformed back again into `t.pl`. During those three seconds I did a `cp t t1` and the `t1` remains without extension, even if I execute it. Following your advice I removed `t.pl` and copied `cp t1 t`, and the new file name seems to remain stable. What happened? Who was the evil spirit changing my file's name? BBEdit?

Comment: I have lost touch about the newer versions of macOS, but the file system used to store files using a file name and an additional MD5 hash, which allowed it to find files back should they have been moved or renamed and even allowed open applications to be moved.  So, if you, at one point, saved the file accidentally as `t.pl` and opened it (with an editor/itself) and then simply renamed it `t` while still opened, whatever had a tap on that file may have renamed it back.  Copying the file as `t1` and then back to `t` will change the MD5 hash, so any other program likely lost track on the file.

Comment: It's related to BBEdit then. Is there anything in the preferences or similar which tries to automatically add suffixes.

Comment: @Phoenix macOS has never used such a system with MD5 hashes as far as I know. It is pretty standard on Unixoid systems (including macOS) that you can move, rename, etc. open files (including applications). The programs that have these file open do not access them by filename or path, but rather by inode.

Comment: @jksoegaard Thanks for correcting. It had been quite some time when I read it (10+ years?) and I may have misinterpreted it back then.  It just got stuck with me that way. Though the principle in this regard is the same with inodes:  As long as the file is “just” renamed/moved, the inode stays the same and copying a file would change the inode, which makes it a different file.

Comment: @Phoenix The big difference is that inodes do not change when the file content changes, but MD5 hashes do. Similarly when you create a hardlink between two files it is based on the inode.

Comment: @jksoegaard, when you gave the explanation with the inode, it all made sense.  Have been “moving on” to Linux a while back now and see the parallels.  Thanks again for the explanation!